# Manage Navigation between 2 or more storyboards

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am developing an app which contains multiple storyboards, and i need to push a particular ViewController from different storyboards, also, i want to manage the navigation between one or more viewcontrollers

Example:
 VieController1 in storyboard1 push to ViewController2 in storyboard2, when i push backbutton in ViewController2, i want to go back to ViewController1, is that possible? How can i do this?

I have tried with a storyboard reference, but the navigation doesn't work 
Thanks!

Comment: Is your "ViewController1" embedded in a `UINavigationController`? If so it should work with a storyboard segue...

Comment: Yes, my viewController1 is embedded in a UINavigationController, but in the second storyboard there is other UINavigationController, could this cause conflicts with the navigation?

Comment: What error are you getting on storyboard segue?

Comment: Yes push navigation works on UIViewController not on UINavigationController. No need to embed VC 2 in UINavigationController

Comment: The problem is that i need to keep the UINavigationController in storyboard2, because i could call the 2nd storyboard from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use one navigation controller for multiple storyboards. You have to make sure --

(1) For the first storyboard, its first view controller is embedded in a navigation controller, and **the navigation controller** "Is Initial View Controller"; and

(2) For the second storyboard, its first view controller is embedded in a navigation controller, and **that view controller** "Is Initial View Controller".

So in the end, in your second storyboard, there will be two arrows pointing to the view controller -- one from the navigation controller, one from no where (indicating it's the initial view controller). See the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it possible :)

You need Navigation Controller stack. If you want make push.  In your controller from make push must have UInavigationController!

If you present modal(over current controller), you need to take care of returning back, call dismiss(_:) function in presented controller.

Interface Builder has "Storyboard reference" for do it.

[image: IB Storyboard reference]

In Attributes Inspector you set storyboard which will show and controller from this storyboard if needed

[image: Storyboard reference Attribute Inspector]

And create segue to this Storyboard reference (right click and drag to storyboard reference)

[image]